# Residues, singularities

Tags: complex-analysis

> For $t\in\mathbb R$ and $n=1,2,3,\dots$ let
>   $$f_n(z)=\frac{z^n}{1-2z\cos t +z^2}$$
>   Find the singularities of $f_n$ inside $B_2=\{z\in\mathbb C:|z|<2\}$, determine their types, and compute their residues.

I'm not really sure how to find the singularities, normally I'd substitute 
$$\cos(t)=\frac{\exp(it)+\exp(-it)}{2} $$ and $$z=\exp(it)$$ however this just gives me zero

Comment: Since $-1 \leq cos(t) \leq 1$ we can think of the denominator as $z^2 -2kz + 1, k \in [-1,1]$. This only has two roots which can be calculated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since
$$
1-2z\cos t+z^2=(z-\cos t)^2+1-\cos^2t=(z-\cos t)+\sin^2t=(z-e^{it})(z-e^{-it}),
$$
then, for $t\ne k\pi, k\in \mathbb{Z}$, the function
$$
f_n(z)=\frac{z^n}{1-2z\cos t+z^2}
$$
has simple poles at 
$$
z_1=e^{it}\, \mbox{ and }\, z_2=e^{-it}=\overline{z_1},
$$ 
and the corresponding residues are:
$$
\mbox{Res}_{z_1}f_n=\frac{z_1^n}{-2\cos t+2z_1}=-i\frac{e^{int}}{2\sin t},\quad \mbox{Res}_{z_2}f_n=\frac{z_2^n}{-2\cos t+2z_2}=i\frac{e^{-int}}{2\sin t}.
$$
For $t=k\pi$ the function $f_n$ has a pole of order $2$ at
$$
z_0=(-1)^k.
$$
The corresponding residue is
$$
\mbox{Res}_{z_0}f_n=\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{d}{dz}\left[(z-z_0)^2f_n(z)\right]=\lim_{z\to z_0}nz^{n-1}=nz_0^{n-1}=n(-1)^{(n-1)k}
$$

Comment: if I was to solve for the contour, integrating over the circle C with radius $2$ about the point $0$, would I consider all three singularity points? or just the first two?

Comment: You'll have to consider two different cases, i.e. when $t \ne k\pi$ and when $t=k\pi$. In the first case there are two singularities, and there is one the second.